# Count and sum condition greater than something

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

I have a table.

[image]

I want count for those users whose summation of coin is more than 2000. For summation I will take only those rows where transaction_type is debited.

my query is something ===>

```
SELECT COUNT(*)  FROM user_coins_log
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING SUM(if(transaction_type = 'Debited',coin,0))>20000
```

But instead of getting one count I am getting lots of rows of count. How to solve this problem.

Comment: Count the number of rows returned. (Have this as a sub-query.)

Comment: what COUNT(*) is doing here ?  Can you explain me please

Comment: 2000!=20000.....

Comment: Yes got it but thats not my question

Comment: You get one row for each user now (with HAVING fulfilled.) The count(*) counts a user's number of rows (transactions.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use two levels of aggregation:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT user_id, SUM(coin) as sum_debits
      FROM user_coins_log
      WHERE transaction_type = 'Debited'
      GROUP BY user_id
      HAVING sum_debits >20000
     ) u;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the query to find all indebted users as a subquery, then count.

Doing the filtering by transaction type in a where clause is a bit simpler.

```
select count(user_id) from (
  select user_id
  from user_coins_log
  where transaction_type = 'Debited'
  group by user_id
  having sum(coin) > 2000
) indebted
```

[Try it](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ad087055f3458c71bdfb4f112a55ccda).